# Transformation matrix issues

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm learning about computer graphics through [modern OpenGL tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5/), and I'm having issues refactoring my code from GLM to a custom matrix math class. Using GLM I can achieve the desired effect (which is a pyramid-like shape rotating across the screen); however, using my math class I cannot get the correct transformation. For reference, [this](http://imgur.com/1pK5YpE) is what the transformation looks like with my math class. Using GLM the shape will translate along the x-axis (horizontally) which is what I want. I assume the GLSL code is correct since it works with the GLM code.

In my `Transform` class, I have a function that returns a model matrix and which maps to the corresponding uniform variable in my shader class.

```
Matrix4f Transform::getModel() const // my math class - not working
{
    Matrix4f transMat, rotMat, scaleMat;
    transMat.initTranslation(trans.x, trans.y, trans.z);
    rotMat.initRotation(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z);
    scaleMat.initScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);

    return transMat * rotMat * scaleMat;
}

glm::mat4 Transform::getModel() const // glm - works fine
{
    glm::mat4 transMat = glm::translate(glm::vec3(trans.x, trans.y, trans.z));
    glm::mat4 scaleMat = glm::scale(glm::vec3(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z));
    glm::mat4 rotX = glm::rotate(rot.x, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotY = glm::rotate(rot.y, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotZ = glm::rotate(rot.z, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    glm::mat4 rotMat = rotX * rotY * rotZ;

    return transMat * rotMat * scaleMat;
}
```

I think the problem lies in my `Matrix4<T>` class, but there's quite a bit of code to show so I will [link.](https://github.com/zmertens/BennyBoxEngine-SFML/blob/develop/include/Matrix4.hpp) The Matrix class is based on the tutorials I linked above.

P.S. If you're wondering why I'm using a custom math class instead of GLM it is for learning purposes (I realize GLM is much more suited for this than my untested library).

Comment: Try adding a bunch of print statements. Print out each matrix in the the GLM method and also using your custom class. In theory they should be identical at each stage. This will allow you to narrow down where the bug occurs.

Comment: I think I found an issue. When I create my 4x4 translation matrix, I initialize the x, y, and z values in the 4th column (with the w value being 1). But in GLM they initialize the 4th ROW. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: It might just be which way round the matrix is ordered, row major or column major. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order.

Comment: Storing your matrices in row major or column major order is a design decision, but you need to make sure that when you upload your matrices to the shader that OpenGL knows which format they are stored in when you call glUniformMatrix*. The 3rd parameter indicates whether or not the matrix needs to be transposed. Since you are storing your matrices the opposite way of what glm does then just flip that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments, all I needed to do was change the 3rd parameter in glUniformMatrix* which performed a transpose on the transformation matrix.